limit user's comments to 2 most recent for every user in Powerbi
I have a table that looks like this: ID, Additional Comments, worknotes.
ID is a key here. Each user may have multiple comments daily along with multiple timestamps
How do I get 2 latest comments (PowerBi ) for each user?
Output should be similar to the original table, just limit user's comments to 2 most recent for every user.
Please refer attached image
just limit user's comments to 2 most recent for every user
